# Excel Conditional Formatting an table based on a list of values (extensive formula to determine list)

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have an array of values.

[Array of values and the desired end result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yOn8.png)

I'm looking to highlight the cells in column A, B, C and D that are within the top 5 of the largest relative portion to column Divider.

i.e. Row 1 Column D the value 4 is 80% of Row 1 Column Divider.

---

I've created a formula that gives me the value of the cells which are the largest relative portion to their connected Divider.

First to calculate the relative portion:

[The result of formula "=Test[[A]:[D]]/Test[Divider]"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nByL4.png)

Then to calculate the lowest value of the Top 5:
"=LARGE(VSTACK(Test[A]/Test[Divider],Test[B]/Test[Divider],Test[C]/Test[Divider],Test[D]/Test[Divider]),5)"
The end result is 0.8

To find the top 5 of the table I've first vertically stacked the 4 columns A through D. Then I vertically stacked the relative portions of the columns A through D. The next step was to horizontally stack these two vertical stacks.

Vertical stack formula of absolute values: "=VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]],Test[[B]:[B]],Test[[C]:[C]],Test[[D]:[D]])"

Vertical stack formula of relative portions: "=VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]])"

Horizontal stack formula of vertical stacks:
"=HSTACK(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]],Test[[B]:[B]],Test[[C]:[C]],Test[[D]:[D]]),VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]]))"

This array then needs to be filtered based on the relative portions, compared to the 5th highest value in the array.

The formula to achieve this is:
"=FILTER(HSTACK(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]],Test[[B]:[B]],Test[[C]:[C]],Test[[D]:[D]]),VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]])),CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]],Test[[B]:[B]],Test[[C]:[C]],Test[[D]:[D]]),VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]])),2)>=LARGE(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]]),5))"

Then I need to only takes the absolute values, as they are the values found in the original table.

The CHOOSECOLS function works perfectly for this.

The formula then becomes:
"=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(HSTACK(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]],Test[[B]:[B]],Test[[C]:[C]],Test[[D]:[D]]),VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]])),CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]],Test[[B]:[B]],Test[[C]:[C]],Test[[D]:[D]]),VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]])),2)>=LARGE(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]]),5)),1)"

[The result of this formula.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDXJF.png)

With this list in hand, I googled how to apply the list to conditional formatting.

[Conditionally format cells in an array based on values in a separate array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70963342/conditionally-format-cells-in-an-array-based-on-values-in-a-separate-array)

[Excel: highlight cell if exists in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033064/excel-highlight-cell-if-exists-in-list)

Based on these answers I tried to create a similar formula. The COUNTIF method gave me an immediate error. Thus I tried the VLOOKUP method.

This is the formula:
"=VLOOKUP(A3,CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(HSTACK(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]],Test[[B]:[B]],Test[[C]:[C]],Test[[D]:[D]]),VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]])),CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]],Test[[B]:[B]],Test[[C]:[C]],Test[[D]:[D]]),VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]])),2)>=LARGE(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]]),5)),1),1,0)=A3"

Now, when using this formula in the conditional formatting, I get the following error:

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8QaF.png)

Part of me thought the cause of this might be the #N/A values coming from the formula. Thus I adapted the formula to cover this and turn the #N/A cells into FALSE.

The formula:
"=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A3,CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(HSTACK(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]],Test[[B]:[B]],Test[[C]:[C]],Test[[D]:[D]]),VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]])),CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]],Test[[B]:[B]],Test[[C]:[C]],Test[[D]:[D]]),VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]])),2)>=LARGE(VSTACK(Test[[A]:[A]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[B]:[B]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[C]:[C]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]],Test[[D]:[D]]/Test[[Divider]:[Divider]]),5)),1),1,0)=A3),FALSE,TRUE)"

[The result of the formula when dragged across a same sized area as the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/145BE.png)

This formula throws the same error when entered into the conditional formatting.

At this point I feel a need to reach out to more experienced Excel developers, to see if they can figure out what I'm doing wrong, or if they know a simpler way to achieve the end result.

Cheers!

Comment: I had more images to show the results of each of the formulas. Sadly Stackoverflow flagged the question as spam if I added those pictures.

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping a night on it, I've come up with a solution to my specific problem.

I'm currently under the impression that the conditional formatting formula doesn't accept table references.

Regardless, the solution was to calculate the relative value, and compare that to the LARGE statement provided above.

This results in a formula for the conditional formatting like so:
"=A3/$E3>=LARGE(VSTACK($A$3:$A$7/$E$3:$E$7,$B$3:$B$7/$E$3:$E$7,$C$3:$C$7/$E$3:$E$7,$D$e:$D$7/$E$3:$E$7),5)"

Which works perfectly!